# Python 2.7 tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile returns object in type 'instance' not 'file'. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, temporary-files

Some libraries checking whether type of input **f** is **file** or not. And Python 2.7 library **tempfile** returns object in type **file** for

```
type(tempfile.TemporaryFile())  # type is file
```

And for

```
type(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile())  # type is instance
```

Is there some reason or it is just a bug?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug because everything behaves as documented.  No guarantees are made about _what type_ actually gets returned from either function -- only that it is "file-like".  Now the $1M question ... Why does it matter to you?  Is there some some other (possibly related) problem that we can help you with?

Comment: @mgilson Maybe it is just curiosity?

Comment: @glglgl -- Possibly (and that's an OK reason).  But, I'm guessing that it has to do with the first line:  "Some libraries checking whether type of input f is file or not."

Comment: No, I told that some library checks if I passed for it file or not. And it checked it like `if isinstance(input_file, file)`. So my code doesn't work since I need to have named temporary file and use it with this third-party library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/tempfile.py#l372), both `TemporaryFile` and `NamedTemporaryFile` are actually factory functions.  Depending on the OS, `TemporaryFile` can simply returns a low-level file handle (on non-posix compliant systems and cygwin, `TemporaryFile` *is* `NamedTemporaryFile`).  `NamedTemporaryFile` always returns an instance of `_TemporaryFileWrapper`, which is an old-style class (hence the `'instance'`) that wraps a low-level file handle.

I would not say that this is a bug (though, maybe qwirky due to the naming convention not following PEP8) as everything behaves according to the documentation -- After all, the returned values *are file-like*.

Comment: But the problem is that it looks like file, have all the methods as file-object has but when some library checks is argument file-object or not, this library will fall with type == instance not file.

Answer (score 5):

Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) for NamedTemporaryFile:

> The returned object is always a file-like object whose `file` attribute is the underlying true file object. This file-like object can be used in a `with` statement, just like a normal file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had with NamedTemporaryFile is that pylint complained that the result was not an iterable.  Probably this is a bug in pylint.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

'''
Test program for pylint complaint about file-like object returned from
tempfile functions.
'''

import tempfile

cmdOut = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix="tmp-scc-cmd-stderr")
print "Return value from NamedTemporaryFile() is %s" % type(cmdOut)

print >>cmdOut, "foo\nbar"              # send two lines of output

cmdOut.seek(0)                          # go back to beginning to read output
for line in cmdOut:
    print line.rstrip()
```

The reported type is 'instance'.

```
% python ~/perl/tempfile-pylint.py
Return value from NamedTemporaryFile() is <type 'instance'>
foo
bar
```

However pylint complains that

```
E: 14,12: Non-iterable value cmdOut is used in an iterating context (not-an-iterable)
```

I agree this isn't a bug in tempfile, but does create a bit of confusion in cases like this.